# Xpath to get all elements with at least one attribute

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I am working with xpath, xml and xsl, so in my project I need to find all elements that have at least one attribute. For example, if I have this xml content:

```
<catalog>
<show>
  <titulo>so so</titulo>
  <ano>1991</ano>
</show>
<sound id="1">some string song</sound>
```

I would want to have only sound node as a result.

I have already tried this xpath

```
count(@*) > 0
```

and

```
string-lenght(@*) > 0
```

But till now none of this solved the issue.

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
//*[@*]
```

Tested with https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html#ad-output using XML from the sample input
Your code is also processed as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
//*[count(@*) > 0]/node()
```

or

```
//*[count(@*) > 0]/text()
```